# How to identify a column name by a string? django/python

Tags: python, django

I am writing a basic function that takes three arguments, request, field, and user_id.
The idea is, when you pass through the info, the function returns the result which would be the column (identified by argument "field"), the row (identified by the argument "user_id").
this is my function:

```
def get_user_field(request, user_id, field):
    result = Users.objects.raw("SELECT id, %s FROM blog_users WHERE id = %s", [field, user_id])[0]
    #return result.??????
```

what I do not know how to do is to replace those question marks with what to return the corresponding column. If i try

```
return result.field
```

It will pass a string where "field" is. And of course a string cannot be put there.

So how can i achieve a function that works pretty much exactly like this and returns one result?

Thanks!

Comment: A little rusty on my Django, but it is quite possibly `getattr(result, field)`.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with the `getattr` Python builtin:

```
return getattr(result, field)
```

But it would be better to do it entirely differently:

```
def get_user_field(request, user_id, field):
    return User.objects.filter(id=user_id).values_list(field, flat=True)[0]
```

Or, to allow for the possibility of the user not existing:

```
def get_user_field(request, user_id, field):
    result = User.objects.filter(id=user_id).values_list(field, flat=True)
    if result:
        return result[0]
    else:
        return None # or raise an exception or whatever you like
```